# Probability of being alergic given that does not pratice sports

Tags: probability, statistics

> In a city, it's estimated that $20\%$ of people have some type of
>   alergy. I'ts known that $50\%$ of alergic people pratice sports, while
>   this percentage for the non alergic people is $40\%$. For an
>   individual chosen randomly in ths city, find the **probability that
>   this person is alergic given that it does not pratice sports**

**While I was writing this exercise I found my error so I'm just gonna leave it here to help people**

I denoted by $A$ the event "alergic" and $S$ for sports. So, the exercise wants to know $P(A|S^c)$ which is by bayes theorem:

$$P(A|S^c) = \frac{P(S^c|A)P(A)}{P(S^c)}$$

Well, $P(S^c|A) = 0.5$ since if $50\%$ of alergic people pratice, $50\%$ does not. The probability of being alergic is $20\%$ as said in the exercise. Now, $P(S^c)$ is the probability of: being alergic and do not pratice sports + not being alergic and do not pratice sports = $0.2\cdot 0.5 + 0.8 + 0.6$, so the result is:

$$P(A|S^c) = \frac{P(S^c|A)P(A)}{P(S^c)} = \frac{0.5\cdot 0.2}{0.2\cdot 0.5 + 0.8 \cdot 0.6} = 0.172413\cdots$$

Turns out my error was that I was writing $P(S^c|A)$ as $0.5\cdot 0.2$ instead of just $0.5$